# Proving that $\sum{}_0^\infty z^{2^n} $ is unbounded when $z \rightarrow 1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I understand **boundedness of series** this way:

1. A series is "**unbounded**" if **the sequence of partial sums are unbounded.**
2. The **sequence of partial sums is unbounded** if I can prove that for an arbitrary bound $M_n$ on the sequence $A_n$  I can always find a bound larger than it ( $M_n < H_n$).

So if I want to show that  $\sum{}_0^\infty z^{2^n} $ is unbounded when z $\rightarrow 1 $, then I need show that the sequence of partial sums  $A_m =\sum{}_0^m z^{2^n}$ cannot be bounded when $z \rightarrow 1$.

I just need some indication of what **how to proceed** as I am sure I am still missing something **conceptually important**.

Comment: What do you mean by $z \rightarrow 1$? Does $z=1$?

Comment: If you're writing $z\to1$ (really, $z\to1^-$), that means you are talking about the sum for multiple different values of $z$, which means you are talking about multiple different sums. We are not talking about the unboundedness of *"a"* sum. Instead, we are talking about the unboundedness of a *function* defined on $(-1,1)$ and that function is defined by $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{2^n}$. Indeed, that sum converges for every individual value of $z$ in the domain.

Comment: Let $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2^n}$ and $f_k(x) = \sum_{n=0}^k x^{2^n}$. We are simply saying that $f$ and $f_k$ are increasing on $[0,1]$, that $f(x)\ge f_k(x)$ and $f_k(1) = k+1$.

Comment: If you like complication, try the sequential approach, a contradiction proof. Let $\{z_n\}$ be a strictly increasing sequence with $z_1 = 1/2$ and $z_n \rightarrow 1$. Suppose the statement is not true. Let $\epsilon > 0$, then there is $N$ s.t. for all $l>N$, $|z_l - 1| < \epsilon$. Furthermore, for $n \geq m \geq l \geq N$, $|A_n - A_m| = \left|\sum_{k=m}^n z_l^{2^k}\right|< \epsilon$.
If you can combine this with the inequality that RRL suggests, I think it will work. Maybe.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about the unboundeness@user1952009 !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all $m \in \mathbb{N}$

$$\sup_{z \in (1-\delta,1)}\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{2^n} > \sup_{z \in (1-\delta,1)}\sum_{n=0}^m z^{2^n} >  \sup_{z \in (1-\delta,1)} (m+1)z^{2^m} = m+1$$

Thus,

$$\limsup_{z \to 1-} \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{2^n} = \lim_{\delta \to 0} \sup_{z \in (1-\delta,1)}\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{2^n} > m+1$$

for all $m \in \mathbb{N}$, implying

$$\limsup_{z \to 1-} \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{2^n} = +\infty, $$

and $S(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{2^n} $ is unbounded. (There is a sequence $z_k \to 1$ such that $S(z_k) \to +\infty$.)

Comment: What is the limit in this taken to? I can't tell whether $z \rightarrow 1_-$ is for the limit or the supremum.

Comment: Added above.  By definition of $\limsup$ as $z \to 1-$ as the limit of the supremum we see that it must be infinite implying that the sum is unbounded.

Answer (score 2):

If
$mz < 1$
then
$(1-z)^m
\ge 1-mz$
(standard proof by induction).

Then,
if
$z > 1-1/2^{m+k}$
where $k \ge 2$
then

$\begin{array}\\
A_m 
&=\sum_{n=0}^m z^{2^n}\\
&\gt\sum_{n=0}^m (1-1/2^{m+k})^{2^n}\\
&\ge\sum_{n=0}^m (1-2^n/2^{m+k})\\
&=m+1-\sum_{n=0}^m 2^n/2^{m+k}\\
&=m+1-2^{-m-k}\sum_{n=0}^m 2^n\\
&=m+1-2^{-m-k}(2^{m+1}-1)\\
&>m+1-2^{1-k}\\
&> m\\
\end{array}
$.

Therefore
$A_m$
can can be made
arbitrarily large
by choosing $m$ large
and then choosing
 $z> 1-1/2^{m+2}$.

Comment: Thank you! Only thing that was not intuitive to me was that first statement...but I will try to work that out.

Comment: True for m=1. Assume true for m, show true for m+1.